¿Cómo resolver error Unexpected Exception de Maven con Spring en ApacheNetbeans 22?
Tengo instalado OpenJDK 21
Apache Netbeans 22
Y estoy en el SO Fedora
Soy nuevo en el tema de Maven, Spring.
Hice un nuevo proyecto con Apache Netebeans 22, lo hice con Java with Maven > Spring Boot Initialzr project.
En vez de usar Spring Initialzr en la web, Instalé el plugin para NetBeans y con esa librería dentro de Netbeans puedo hacer el proyecto de Spring.
Hasta ahí todo bien. Me genera todo el proyecto, con el archivo pom.xml su contenido es el siguiente:
Código pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>mx.com.gm</groupId>
<artifactId>HolaSpring</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>HolaSpring</name>
<description>HolaMundo con Spring</description>
<url/>
<licenses>
    <license/>
</licenses>
<developers>
    <developer/>
</developers>
<scm>
    <connection/>
    <developerConnection/>
    <tag/>
    <url/>
</scm>
<properties>
    <java.version>21</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>                                                 
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>

El IDE me dice el siguiente error, en notificaciones:
Unexpected Exception
For artifact: {org.projectlombok:lombok:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.

Y los detalles del error es el siguiente:
org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {org.projectlombok:lombok:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty.
at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:162)
at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:142)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.api.PluginPropertyUtils.getPluginPathProperty(PluginPropertyUtils.java:812)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.classpath.AnnotationProcClassPathImpl.getCompileArtifacts(AnnotationProcClassPathImpl.java:94)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.classpath.AnnotationProcClassPathImpl.createPath(AnnotationProcClassPathImpl.java:67)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.classpath.AbstractProjectClassPathImpl.getPath(AbstractProjectClassPathImpl.java:153)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.classpath.AbstractProjectClassPathImpl.getResources(AbstractProjectClassPathImpl.java:144)
at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath.entries(ClassPath.java:363)
at org.netbeans.modules.maven.classpath.ClassPathProviderImpl$AnnotationPathSelector.getActiveClassPath(ClassPathProviderImpl.java:685)
at org.netbeans.spi.java.classpath.support.MuxClassPathImplementation.getActiveClassPath(MuxClassPathImplementation.java:156)
at org.netbeans.spi.java.classpath.support.MuxClassPathImplementation.getResources(MuxClassPathImplementation.java:89)
at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath.entries(ClassPath.java:363)
at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath.getRoots(ClassPath.java:248)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.APTUtils.listenOnProcessorPath(APTUtils.java:343)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.APTUtils.listen(APTUtils.java:329)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.APTUtils.create(APTUtils.java:234)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.indexing.APTUtils.get(APTUtils.java:181)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.createJavacTask(JavacParser.java:897)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.CompilationInfoImpl.getJavacTask(CompilationInfoImpl.java:460)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.CompilationInfoImpl.getJavacTask(CompilationInfoImpl.java:438)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.getResult(JavacParser.java:531)
at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParser.getResult(JavacParser.java:140)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor.callGetResult(TaskProcessor.java:608)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.SourceCache.getResult(SourceCache.java:241)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$RequestPerformer.run(TaskProcessor.java:775)
at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:288)
at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$RequestPerformer.execute(TaskProcessor.java:702)

[catch]  at org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor$CompilationJob.run(TaskProcessor.java:663)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
 
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1420)
at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:287)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2035)

¿NO entiendo bien claramente de dónde exactamente está el error y por qué?
Podrían aayudarme, de antemano gracias.

Despues de una semana de investigación, encontré la solución. En el archivo de pom.xml debemos añadir la versión de Lombok, en la parte de annotationProcessorPaths
El código pom.xml completo quedaría así:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>mx.com</groupId>
<artifactId>HolaSpring</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>HolaSpring</name>
<description>Hola con Spring Boot</description>
<url/>
<licenses>
    <license/>
</licenses>
<developers>
    <developer/>
</developers>
<scm>
    <connection/>
    <developerConnection/>
    <tag/>
    <url/>
</scm>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>                
            <configuration>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version> <!-- Aquí ponemos esta línea -->
                    </path>                        
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>    

Y el error queda resuelto.
